# How to change Orientation of bars in Excel Bar Chart created with VBA

Tags: excel, excel-charts, vba

I am creating a chart, in a form, using VBA Excel 2010. I have configured excel to use Chartspace and the chart is created using dynamic data correctly, but the presentation is not what I am looking for, but can't figure how to change it. Please see the section of code:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
Dim row_count As Integer
Dim n As Long
Dim chart_data As Worksheet

Set chart_data = Worksheets("Sheet3")
row_count = chart_data.UsedRange.Rows.Count

Dim varCats()
Dim varVals()

ReDim varCats(row_count)
ReDim varVals(row_count)

'Set c = ChartSpace1.Constants
Set mychart = ChartSpace1.Charts.Add
mychart.Type = xlColumnClustered '51 'chChartTypeBarClustered 'c.chChartTypeBarClustered

For n = 2 To row_count
    varCats(n) = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet3").Range("A" & n).Value
    varVals(n) = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet3").Range("T" & n).Value
Next n

mychart.SeriesCollection.Add
With mychart.SeriesCollection(0)
    .SetData chDimSeriesNames, chDataLiteral, "QAR Score"
    .SetData chDimCategories, chDataLiteral, varCats
    .SetData chDimValues, chDataLiteral, varVals
End With
```

End Sub

The bar chart is showing the bars horizontally and not vertically. So where I thought my variable "varCats" would go to the X-Axis is not but rather the Y-axis.

I know this is going to be a simple response from the community, but I have yet to find it through my searching.

Thanks,
C

Image from the answer provide:
[image]

Desired Results:
[image]

Comment: Which version of Excel, and which version of OWC are you using?

Comment: Microsoft Office Chart 11.0 is enabled from "Additional Controls." Excel 2010.

Comment: Have you tried `mychart.Type = chChartTypeColumnClustered`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Revised to work with ChartSpace objects in UserForm

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Dim row_count As Integer
    Dim n As Long
    Dim chart_data As Worksheet
    Dim srs As ChSeries
    Dim myChart As ChChart

    Set chart_data = Worksheets("Sheet3")
    row_count = chart_data.UsedRange.Rows.Count

    ReDim varCats(1 To row_count)
    ReDim varVals(1 To row_count)

    varCats = Application.Transpose(chart_data.Range("A2:A" & row_count).Value)
    varVals = Application.Transpose(chart_data.Range("T2:B" & row_count).Value)

    'Set c = ChartSpace1.Constants
    Set myChart = ChartSpace1.Charts.Add
        myChart.Type = chChartTypeColumnClustered
    Set srs = myChart.SeriesCollection.Add
        With srs
            .SetData chDimSeriesNames, chDataLiteral, "QAR Score"
            .SetData chDimCategories, chDataLiteral, varCats
            .SetData chDimValues, chDataLiteral, varVals
        End With



End Sub
```

Comment: This still produced columns oriented horizontally , and is NOW (my bad) 3D.  I also did a macro, it gave me the same `Type` and still generated a 3-D horizontal bar chart.

Comment: can you please clarify: "columns" are always vertical, "bars" are always horizontal. You seem to be using the two terms interchangeably, and this is confusing. Consider adding a screenshot of the current output, and also of the desired output.

Comment: Also, please note that you do not mention anything about 3-d.  So, please revise to describe what you actually want, in more detail.

Comment: So my desired results would be columns, yet the return is bars. I want 2 dimensional, yet the return, based on the answer, is now 3-D. I will upload images.

Comment: The 3d chart you display is not possibly produced by the code I provided. Can you include ALL of your code? It is possible you have some code elsewhere that is changing the chart type.

Comment: OK, are you trying to add this chart to a ChartSheet or a Worksheet?

Comment: The "project" has 2 forms, one that takes in data, and on button click enters it into an excel worksheet. The second form, is a form with a ChartSpace object on the form that takes the data from the worksheet and displays it.

Comment: This fixed it `mychart.Type = chChartTypeColumnClustered`

Comment: I revised my answer above, I think it will clean up your code a little bit, too.